# Problemas con el host en gitb hub pages de un proyecto en React y react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, github

Cuando subo mis proyectos a git hub pages, al entrar a la pagina no entra en escena el componente Home.

Mi Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/App.js';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './global.css';

const container = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
```

Mi App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Badges from '../pages/Badges';
import BadgeNew from '../pages/BadgeNew';
import BadgeDetailsContainer from '../pages/BadgeDetailsContainer';
import BadgeEdit from '../pages/BadgeEdit';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/badges" component={Badges} />
                <Route exact path="/badge/new" component={BadgeNew} />
                <Route exact path="/badge/:badgeId" component={BadgeDetailsContainer} />
                <Route exact path="/badge/:badgeId/edit" component={BadgeEdit} />

            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Cuando entro a la pagina el path es `https://s-arzuaga.github.io/agendaweb/`

En lugar de cargar el componente Home, no carga ninguno y solo se ve el Navbar.

Lo cree con create-react-app.

Comment: pareciera que `/agendaweb` no existe como `Route` dentro del `Switch`. Tendrías que crear tal ruta para que funcionase, a menos que quieras usar tu componente `Home` como fallback para cuando una rtua no existe...

Comment: @Japsz Ya intente cambiar el path a `/agenda` en lugar de `/` pero tampoco funcionó.

Comment: Y si mueves el componente `<Navbar />` dentro de los otros componentes y lo sacas de tu `App.js`? Sé que es un poco engorroso, pero algo debe estar haciendo ese _<Navbar />_ que te causa el problema

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Hmmm no había pensado que podía ser el Navbar el problema, voy a intentar ponerlo dentro de un layout.

Comment: Lo que pasa, es que al acceder a tu sitio, efectivamente se muestra solo el Navbar, pero si pinchas el logo te redirecciona al Home y todo funciona normal @santizic